# how to ignore the TimeoutException and continue to run the code?

Tags: python, selenium

I'm extracting a demand/supply/competitiveness data by putting keywords(which is from 디지털가전.xlsx) into the website (https://itemscout.io/keyword/). The problem is that if the keyword can't be analyzed in this website and doesn't show any data of demand/supply/competitiveness, because of the timeoutexception,it will stop running. I want it to continue to run even though it doesn't show any data. How do I solove this problem?

```
raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

this is the file where keywords are stored
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1oKIXZWiw5WsazHBstKVT8UlgRSZfdx62/view
last column of the excel file contains the keyword

```
import xlrd
import pandas as pd
import xlrd
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import openpyxl
import time
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException


driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Users\Kim woo jae\PycharmProjects\100개 키워드\chromedriver.exe")
list = []
list1 = []
list2 = []
list3 = []

driver.get("https://itemscout.io/keyword/")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 120)
b = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="container"]/div/div[2]/div/input')))
b.clear()
b.send_keys('화장대')
c = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="container"]/div/div[2]/div/span')))
c.click()
d = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="container"]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/table/tbody'))).text

df = pd.read_excel(r'디지털가전.xlsx')
ky = df['키워드']

for k in ky:
    b1 = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="container"]/div/div[2]/div/input')))
    b1.clear()
    b1.send_keys(k)
    # c1 = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="container"]/div/div[2]/div/span')))
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="container"]/div/div[2]/div/span'))).click()
    # c1.click()
    time.sleep(2)
    wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="container"]/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/div')))

    d1 = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="container"]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/table/tbody'))).text
    d1 = (d1).replace(',', '.')
    d1 = ' '.join(d1.splitlines())
    d1 = d1.replace(' ', ',')
    result = [x.strip() for x in d1.split(',')]

    d = [result[0]]
    s = [result[1]]
    c = [result[2]]
    print([k],d,s,c)

    for ks in [k]:
        list.append(ks)
    for ds in d:
        list1.append(ds)
    for ss in s:
        list2.append(ss)
    for cs in c:
        list3.append(cs)

df["키워드 확인"] = list
df["총검색량"] = list1
df["공급량"] = list2
df["경쟁률"] = list3


df.to_excel("디지털가전 최종.xlsx")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap the call in a try\except:

```
for k in ky:
   try:
        b1 = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="container"]/div/div[2]/div/input')))
        b1.clear()
        b1.send_keys(k)
        # c1 = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="container"]/div/div[2]/div/span')))
        wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="container"]/div/div[2]/div/span'))).click()
        # c1.click()
        time.sleep(10)
        wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="container"]/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/div')))

        d1 = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="container"]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/table/tbody'))).text
        d1 = (d1).replace(',', '.')
        d1 = ' '.join(d1.splitlines())
        d1 = d1.replace(' ', ',')
        result = [x.strip() for x in d1.split(',')]

        d = [result[0]]
        s = [result[1]]
        c = [result[2]]
        print([k],d,s,c)

        for ks in [k]:
            list.append(ks)
        for ds in d:
            list1.append(ds)
        for ss in s:
            list2.append(ss)
        for cs in c:
            list3.append(cs)
        driver.execute_script("window.history.go(-1)")  # back to search
        driver.refresh() # extra safety
   except TimeoutException:
      print("Got Timeout for Key:", k)
```

Comment: where should put the except TimeoutException: ?

Comment: wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="container"]/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/div')))
if this doesn't appear, I want to continue to run the loop

Comment: Can I ask you one more question, sir? demand/supply/competitiveness data of a keyword sometimes will be printed as same as that of previous keyword, is there anyway I can make it correct? should I increase the amount of time to sleep?

Comment: Are you saying the results are wrong?  Or you just want to remove\skip duplicate data ?

Comment: For example, if the result of keyword A is 1000/1000/1000, the result of following keyword B is 1000/1000/1000, and the result of following keyword C is 1000/1000/1000 the same, when it should be different

Comment: I want to get the correct result of every keyword. But, sometimes I think it's because time .sleep is too short, it appears to have the same results

Comment: It usually occurs in the middle of running the code, I want to wait for the exact result of keyword to be printed

Comment: I updated the code. Wait is now 10 seconds and after each key is processed, the web browser goes back to the first search page so you can't scrape bad data.

Comment: Thank u so much, sir! You are genius

Comment: Sir, is there any way that I don't wait for 10seconds to get the result? Because it took me almost 1 days to get the result.
"d1 = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="container"]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/table/tbody'))).text" 
I already made it to wait for this element to be appeared and get the text data from the element. But if I write time.sleep(3), sometimes the result of keyword A, the result of following keyword B and the result of following keyword C is 1000/1000/1000 the same.

Comment: It's happening in the middle of running the code. Mostly, it can print correct data,but there are still many duplicates. I just want to save some time for running this code because there are almost 5000 keywords in the raw data.